# Working in Mawk; but not in Awk

Tags: bash, awk

This could be a difficult fix, could be a dead simple fix that's glaring me in the eyes and I just can't see it.

In trying to run this `awk` command for file piece1.txt:

```
    awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 {  gsub("~", "", $1); gsub("!", "", $1); gsub("%20", "_", $1); gsub("#", "", $1); gsub("$", "", $1); gsub("%", "", $1); gsub("^", "", $1); gsub("&", "_", $1); gsub("@", "", $1); gsub("*", "", $1); gsub("\(", "", $1); gsub("\)", "", $1); gsub(/ /, "_", $1); gsub("____", "_", $1); gsub("___", "_", $1); gsub("__", "_", $1); print RS } 1' piece1.txt
```

Output error:

```
    awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=piece1.txt FNR=2) fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /(/
```

It seems to run the cmd up until the first instance of "href=", as specified, and then it wipes the rest of the txt file.

I'm led to believe there's just a problem in my code that I'm overlooking. But the strange thing is that this code works perfectly in a Debian/Ubuntu Distro (MAWK is default). It's only in GNU Awk in a Mint KDE distro that I'm getting this error.

If it's relevant:

```
    > awk --version
    > GNU Awk 4.0.1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to quote your regex string further as you used `""` to encapsulate them instead of `//`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 {  gsub("~", "", $1); gsub("!", "", $1); gsub("%20", "_", $1; gsub("#", "", $1); gsub("$", "", $1); gsub("%", "", $1); gsub("^", "", $1); gsub("&", "_", $1); gsub("@", "", $1); gsub("*", "", $1); gsub("\\(", "", $1); gsub("\\)", "", $1); gsub(/ /, "_", $1); gsub("____", "_", $1); gsub("___", "_", $1); gsub("__", "_", $1); print RS } 1' piece1.txt
```

This was the part that was changed: `gsub("\\(", "", $1); gsub("\\)", "", $1);`

I suggest changing your patterns and use `//` instead. It's also more efficient.

You might find this simpler as well:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 { gsub(/(%20|_)+/, "_", $1); gsub(/[~!#$%^&*()@]/, "", $1); print RS } 1' piece1.txt
```

Or

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 { gsub(/%20/, "_", $1); gsub(/[~!#$%^&*()@]/, "", $1); gsub(/_+/, "_", $1); print RS } 1' piece1.txt
```

Comment: Konsolebox, is there a way to exclude a particular pattern from the being converted? One that starts with -- href="SPECIAL_LINK --and ends with-- Subject=" ?

Comment: Next to `NR > 1`, you can add a condition to check `$1` like `NR > 1 && $1 !~ /something/ { ...`

Comment: Probably like `NR > 1 && $1 !~ /^SPECIAL_LINK.*Subject=$/ { ...`

Comment: 2 for 2 for me, Konsole. Thanks!

Comment: Konsole, I've been running the condition, but I'm encountering a strange problem. Rather than excluding the entire entry --href="SPECIAL_LINK..." -- the "href="" keeps getting deleted, leaving only -- SPECIAL_LINK... --.

Comment: Can you tell me that condition part? I'm guessing that you're using `~` and not `!~`.

Comment: Sure: I'm using

awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 && $1 !~ /^SPECIAL_LINK.*Subject=*/ {...'

It's doing the same thing for me in another similar awk command, too.

Comment: Perhaps you missed another `.`: `/^SPECIAL_LINK.*Subject=.*/`

Comment: Good catch, because I did miss that! But, the printed output is still missing "href="".

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the final print option. I have it in as print RS. Do I need to modify that to include the condition fully?

Comment: I think I made a mistake with that sorry. The condition should have been made inside: `awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 { if ($1 !~ /^SPECIAL_LINK.*Subject=.*/) { gsub(/%20/, "_", $1); gsub(/[~!#$%^&*()@]/, "", $1); gsub(/_+/, "_", $1) } print RS } 1' piece1.txt`